# faster join by selecting relevant rows into an aliased table first?

Tags: mysql

I read on SO that `join` is performed before `where` so I was wondering if it is (always) a good idea to perform a join like so:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM tbl_1 WHERE field = 'the_value') t
    JOIN tbl_2 USING (joinable_field)
```

instead of the usual

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_1 t1 JOIN tbl_2 t2 USING (joinable_field)
WHERE t1.field = 'the_value'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this, you are restricting the execution and evaluation order. `t` must be created first (maybe "on the fly", maybe physially on disk), and `tbl_2` is joined in.

In your concrete case, this shouldn't hurt, however. But I cannot see a benefit, either.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you read that? `JOIN` is not performed before `WHERE`. The results should be returned **as if** the Join is performed before Where. The Query optimizer is free to choose whatever path of execution finds best.

The advice may have some value with very complex queries and/ot not very good optimizers.